# OSTicket ticket entries not displaying

Tags: logging, osticket

OSTicket 1.15.4 on self managed VPS: CentOS7, Apache, PHP 7.4.27, MySQL 5.7.37

We are starting to notice tickets that are not presenting any of the existing entries in the view pane below.  In other words, we can see the ticket tab showing "(2)" meaning that there are two correspondence entries, but the view pane below the tab is blank, and none of the action buttons work (can't reply, can't edit, can't create new ticket, can't print).

I can't find any messages or errors in the OST logs, in the PHP console, or in the VPS logs, or emailed to alerts@ourdomain.com.  (PHP is set to Display Errors = true).

We have a second problem where the print ticket button does nothing.  Similarly, there are no messages, errors, notifications, etc...

I suspect that these are permissions issues on the files/folders in the implementation, and or the user/group running the process is incorrect (although we haven't changed anything - or haven't done that knowingly).

Is it possible to enable logging to identify permissions issues when a process is trying to accomplish a task but failing on permissions (without explicit code trapping this condition?). Specifically, I would like a nudge forward to enable whatever debug or logging can help me isolate the problem, anywhere between the VPS and OST (including mySQL, PHP, etc.).